# Show that $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{e^{\iota x}-1}{\iota x}=1$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, limits-without-lhopital, characteristic-functions

> (a) Show that $|e^{\iota a}-e^{\iota b}|\le\min\{2,|a-b|\}$ for all $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. Hint. Write it as an integral from $a$ to $b$.
>
> (b) Show that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{e^{\iota x}-1}{\iota x}=1$$

I have been able to prove part (a) by setting $f(x)=e^{\iota x}$ and using the expansion of $e^{\iota x}$. Assuming part (b) is not unrelated to part (a), how can I possibly prove it? I tried showing the LHS $\le1$ using the fact that $|e^{\iota a}-e^{\iota b}|\le|a-b|$, but am stuck with the other half. Any help?

Comment: Isn't this just $f'(0) / i$, by definition?

Comment: @preferred_anon possibly?  but i was wondering if there was a different method using the fact i proved in (a)

Comment: preferred_anon is right, your limit is of the form $\frac 1i \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$.

Comment: Try using the power series representation.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what is your context/tradition so that you use $\iota$ (iota) for $\sqrt{-1}$, rather than $i$? I'm genuinely curious. :)

Comment: @paulgarrett i think $\iota$ is the generally used symbol for $\sqrt{-1}$. in writing, it just looks like $i$?

Comment: Hm! In my little world, most people write $i$, and a few people write $\sqrt{-1}$, ... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|e^{ix}-1| \leqslant \min (2,|x-0|) = |x|$, so if the limit is defined, it converges with module $\leq 1$. You can't have more from this. You can try working with the real part and the imaginary part but I don't know why you would bother.

Otherwise it is clearly the definition of $\frac{1}{i} \cdot\frac{d}{dx} (e^{ix})(0) = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is $\dfrac{0}{0}$ we apply L'Hospital's rule
\begin{align}
f'(x) &= \frac{i \, exp(ix)}{i} \\
\lim_{x>0} f^{'}(x) &= e^{0} =  1
\end{align}

Comment: Be very careful applying L'Hopital in the complex setting.